# Re-declaring object in a for loop - C++

Tags: c++, loops, variable-declaration

I do have a question on variable re-declaration in loops.

Why declaring an object in a foor loop doesn't trigger the redeclaration error?

Do the object get destroyed and recreated at each iteration of the loop?

I'm inserting a sample code

```
class DataBlock {
    int id;
    string data;
public:
    DataBlock(int tid=0,const string &tdata=""){
        id=tid;
        data=tdata;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ifstream file;
    int temp_id;        //temporary hold the the id read from the file
    string temp_data;   //temporary hold the data read from the file

    set <DataBlock> s;

    //check for command line input here
    file.open(argv[1]);

    //check for file open here
    file >> temp_id >> temp_data;
    while (!file.eof()){
        DataBlock x(temp_id,temp_data);   //Legit, But how's the workflow?
        s.insert(x);
        file >> temp_id >> temp_data;
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Do the object get destroyed and recreated at each iteration of the loop?_ <- You got it

Comment: @Michele Fattoruso This declaration set <DataBlock> s; does not make sense because the comparator is not defined for the class DataBlock.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I didn't include all the code with the overloaded operators, as it wouldn't add additional information to the question asked, but just clutter the code and let people read more line. I do have the comparison operator overloaded for the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why declaring an object in a foor loop doesn't trigger the redeclaration error?

A redeclaration error happens when you declare the same name twice (or more) in the same scope.  That looks like

```
int i = 5;
int i = 6; // uh oh, you already declared i
```

In your loop you don't have that, you just have

```
loop
{
    int i = 5;
}
```

So no redeclaration.

You could also have

```
int i = 5
{
    int i = 6;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

And not have a redeclaration error as the variables are in different scopes and you can have the same variable in multiple scopes.  I this case `6` would be print as that `i` is the `i` that is in scope.

> Do the object get destroyed and recreated at each iteration of the loop?

Yes. Think of a loop as a function that gets called multiple times.  When you enter the body of a loop/function the variables declared in it get constructed<sup>1</sup> and when you reach the end of the loop/function the variables are destroyed.

<sup>1: it is a little more complicated then that but we don't need to get into all those details in this answer</sup>

Comment: thank you for the answer. This confirms what I was thinking. I couldn't find any information about that.

Comment: You may want to clarify that the variable declaration is in the same scope.  The `{` and `}` introduce a new scope, so a declaration of the same variable is allowed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've updated the answer.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

> Why declaring an object in a foor loop doesn't trigger the redeclaration error?

No it does not.

Each time the for loop iterates, a new scope is entered and the objects created in the previous one are destructed and their storage allocation are freed.

```
for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; ++i) {
    MyClass c;
}
```

will be as if:

```
{
    int i=0;
    {
        MyClass c; // c(0)
    } // c destructed, storage allocation freed
    ++i;
    {
        MyClass c; // c(1)
    } // c destructed, storage allocation freed
    ++i;
}
```

`c(0)` and `c(1)` do share the same name, but in scopes without overlapping. Everything is fine.